# Found in diagnostics on an iPhone 6s Plus. Any idea what it means?

Tags: iphone, ios

```
{
    "is_simulated":true,
    "app_name":"Google Maps",
    "timestamp":"2016-06-10 17:10:20.20 -0500",
    "app_version":"4.18.0",
    "slice_uuid":"5fc56151-7941-332f-afaa-3b7fd611e204",
    "adam_id":585027354,
    "build_version":"4.18.81882",
    "bundleID":"com.google.Maps",
    "share_with_app_devs":false,
    "is_first_party":false,
    "bug_type":"109",
    "os_version":"iPhone OS 9.2.1 (13D15)",
    "name":"Google Maps"
}

Incident Identifier: BFFF8177-5800-4AF8-8C80-660970D75897
CrashReporter Key:   0987bf660de545f3fb71e8ee071b1a44a2449887
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,2
Process:             Google Maps [3080]
Path:                /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0BACCEBA-2901-4E5E-8D95-6C453559E446/Google Maps.app/Google Maps
Identifier:          com.google.Maps
Version:             4.18.81882 (4.18.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-06-10 17:10:20.20 -0500
Launch Time:         2016-06-10 14:47:28.28 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  4

Application Specific Information:
<BKNewProcess: 0x14ce18820; com.google.Maps; pid: 3080; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x14ce1a5a0> id: 3080-A369F80A-9505-4726-9D07-20E2364D6EE6 name: GTMSessionFetcher process: <BKNewProcess: 0x14ce18820; com.google.Maps; pid: 3080; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:3080 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x14ce0fdf0> id: 3080-6B151A60-9AA9-4447-8C1C-9C4B2C47B031 name: GTMSessionFetcher process: <BKNewProcess: 0x14ce18820; com.google.Maps; pid: 3080; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:3080 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 5.020 (user 5.020, system 0.000), 3% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.024, 0% CPU

Filtered syslog:
None found
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the exception code that points to:

> 0x8badf00d: Reads as “ate bad food”! (If you squint your eyes and replace the digits with alphabetic characters. :p) This code indicates that an application was terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. Basically, the application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

There's a nice [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) explaining this.

Comment: Dontcha just love devs who do these kinds of things